# How can I interpret the documentation of this serviceClient method?

Tags: ros, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to build a service client.
I went to the reference of the node handle class [here] (http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#aa3376eeca609c4985255cecfaadcbcc5)
It shows this information to build the client:

**ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient  (   const std::string &     service_name,
bool    persistent = false,
const M_string &    header_values = M_string()
)       [inline]**

but I found that it works this way:

**ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient< service_type>(const std::string &   service_name)**

My problem as a newcomer to ROS is how can I get that the **< service_type>** is a part of the command while it is not written in the class reference?

Should I use another documentation or what?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249843/how-can-i-interpret-the-documentation-of-this-serviceclient-method?/) by [Biomacs](https://answers.ros.org/users/25467/biomacs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My problem as a newcomer to ROS is how can I get that the **< service_type>** is a part of the command while it is not written in the class reference?

This is not really a ROS problem, but probably an oversight when you read the documentation for the method.

The `ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient(..)` method is a template method (from [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a183d4cba0ea5c78f075304b91e07cc61)):

```
template<class Service >
ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient ( const std::string & service_name,
                                               bool persistent = false,
                                               const M_string & header_values = M_string() 
                                             ) [inline]
```

Note that the overload you linked to is not the one you actually used (the link is to the `template<class MReq, class MRes >` variant, the one you used is the one above that takes a single `Service` template parameter).

The fact that it's templated is perhaps more visible in the header file, linked in the Doxygen docs: [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/node__handle_8h_source.html#l01246).

> I found that it works this way:

> ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient< service_type>(const std::string & service_name)

Besides the template argument (`service_type` in your example), the arguments other than `service_name` have default values, so that is why your example invocation is also accepted.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0